# Database update with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add the ability to accept or decline a review from mysql database, and I don't know what the problem is. I tryied and searched for 3 hours now, but I can't solve this. The code written in short is:

```
if($row['accept']==1){
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check[]\" value=\"0\">Decline";
}
else{
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check[]\" value=\"1\">Accept";
}

if(isset($_REQUEST) && isset($_POST['check'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['check'])){
        foreach($_POST['check'] as $key => $value){
             mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE feedback_rate SET accept = $value where id=$key");
        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_POST);
        echo "<pre>";
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me and tell me what is the problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Would help if you tell US the problem, then we can tell you the ANSWER. Is there an error, what is its current behavior?

Comment: Your `check[]` fields don't have the ID in the name.

Comment: Well, it's not an error, but it doesn't update the database with the new value, that I inserted in the checkboxe

Comment: well your posting `check[]=0/1` and looking for `check=0/1`, this is what i see tright off the bat

Comment: @Wobbles `name="check[]"` creates an array in `$_POST['check']`, he's iterating through it with `foreach`.

Comment: @Barmar granted my querystring knowledge is not that great, but can you directly cast into an array like that with post data? do you not need to parse it somehow?

Comment: @Wobbles PHP does it automatically for you.

Comment: @Barmar something new learned, in that case I agree, all that seems missing is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `ID` into the `name` attribute:

```
if($row['accept']==1){
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check[{$row['id']}]\" value=\"0\">Decline";
}
else{
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check[{$row['id']}]\" value=\"1\">Accept";
}
```

Otherwise, `$key` in your `foreach` loop will just be the index of the checkbox in the `POST` data.